# Диагонально двигающаяся бесконечная картинка в фоне widget'а в Dart/Flutter

Tags: html, анимация, flutter, layout, background-image

Необходимо реализовать загруженную из интернета картинку в фоне элемента, повторить (repeat=true) по двум осям и анимировать движение по диагонали.

```css
:root {
  --backgroundSize: 150px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/1280px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png);
  background-size: var(--backgroundSize);
  animation: movingBackground 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes movingBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: var(--backgroundSize) var(--backgroundSize);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Пробовал создавать контейнер, в него пихать картинку и анимировать его, но в этом случае едет layout. Как это реализовать так же как в html примере? Не хотелось бы подгружать webkit и нагружать приложение ещё и отрисовкой html кода.